# Panorama Parallax effect (multilayer Imagveiew with offset and speed)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

Now I am looking to setup a multi-layer parallax scrolling background for a application and was wondering how I might go about this. The application will scroll left to right and I am looking to setup three layers, foreground trees, background hills and distant clouds all moving in parallax. Each layer going back will scroll at a slightly slower speed than the layer in-front. Foreground Trees (Front) Background Hills (Middle) Distant Clouds (Back) >>>>>>>>>> Something like Panorama Parallax effect (multilayer Imagveiew with offset and speed) ..> Please help me on this :)

As I tried Viewpager pagination, but not getting multiple layer tarnsition.....